# Cordova App with Apple Watch Not Able to Upload on Apple Store (There is more then one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier Collision)

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, apple-watch

We have created one Cordova app which is live and then we also created the apple watch app using plugin and it was working fine too.

But after some day when we just change some html and try to upload the new version of app to apple store then its give us an error.Its really strenge that it was the same project we upload we did not change anything still its give error. :(

We tried lot solution for that but nothing works. Please help me.
Here is the screenshot of app and error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see that you was able to upload a cordova app with watchOS1 this summer while is not possible. Apple message when I try to upload:

"ERROR ITMS-90636: "Invalid WatchKit Support. Starting June 1, 2016, all new watchOS apps submitted to the App Store must be native apps built with the watchOS 2 SDK or later. iPhone apps that introduce a new WatchKit extension for watchOS 1.0 will no longer be accepted. Learn more about developing for watchOS: https://developer.apple.com/watchos/"

Can you tell me how was possible for you?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally After long research I found the solution.
As there was issue in provisoning and Bundle id.

So here is the Steps Which I follow.

1. We need to create three Bundle Id(1 For App,1 For WatchKit and 1 For Watch Extension)
2. Then you have create group and attach all three together(with PreFix)
3. Then Create the Provisioning Profile Of Each and install in Mac and then all will work Fine.

Hope this Help you :)

Thanks.